# extract a row from matrix

Tags: r, matrix, extract, rows

I have a large matrix where the first 4 rows and columns look like this:

```
             BI00R1 BI00R2 BI00R3 BI08R1
c51581_g1_i1   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00

c19380_g1_i1   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00

c71266_g2_i1   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00

c70836_g2_i9 572.19 513.89 424.49 760.92
```

How can I extract one row, say, the one starting with `'c19380_g1_i1'` from the matrix?
Probably trivial, still I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mat['c19380_g1_i1', ]
```

where `mat` is the name of your matrix.

Comment: As row.names are not necessarily unique in matrix, it's important to precise that the solution will only provide **the first match**.